# Instantiating a new clone of a prefab whilst setting the previous clone as inactive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game where players take turns in spelling a word. I have an input field prefab that is added anytime the player presses a button.
Here is what I have done so far:
These lines of codes instantiate a new input field when the user clicks the done button

```
//show next input field to enter letter
private void ShowInputField(){
    GameObject inputFieldGameObject = inputFieldObjectPool.GetObject();
    inputFieldGameObject.transform.SetParent (inputFieldParent);
    Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases ();
    GameObject.Find ("ScrollView").GetComponent<ScrollRect> ().horizontalNormalizedPosition = 1;
}
```

Here is code for the done button which calls the ShowInputField function and a NextPlayerTurn function:

```
public void DoneButton(){
    NextPlayerTurn ();
    ShowInputField ();
}
```

Now what I want to add is when the done button is pressed the previous instantiated clones of the prefab should be set as inactive with the newly added instantiated prefab the only active prefab so that players cannot edit previously entered letters.

Any help would be kindly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `prevObject.SetActive(false);`? Or rather, `Destroy(prevObject);`?

Comment: @Fredrik can you please elaborate on your comment

Comment: @Abdul Thanks I had the same problem, your question helped me in finding a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a temporary GameObject to hold the last `InputField`. Check if it is `null` after the Button is pressed.

If it is null, there is no last input. If it is not null, there is a last input, get the `InputField` attached to it with `lastInput.GetComponent<InputField>();` then use `InputField.interactable` or `InputField.readOnly` to disable the last `InputField` so that players cannot modify it.

Other variable options you have is the `InputField.enabled` variable. You have to test and decide which one of these variables work best for you.

```
GameObject lastInput = null;

void DeActivateLastInput()
{
    if (lastInput != null)
    {
        InputField inputField = lastInput.GetComponent<InputField>();
        inputField.interactable = false;
        inputField.readOnly = true;
    }
}

//show next input field to enter letter
private void ShowInputField()
{
    GameObject inputFieldGameObject = inputFieldObjectPool.GetObject();
    //Reset this pool since it may have been disabled before from the DeActivateLastInput function
    InputField inputField = inputFieldGameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
    inputField.interactable = true;
    inputField.readOnly = false;

    //Make this Input Last Input
    lastInput = inputFieldGameObject;

    inputFieldGameObject.transform.SetParent(inputFieldParent);
    Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
    GameObject.Find("ScrollView").GetComponent<ScrollRect>().horizontalNormalizedPosition = 1;
}

public void DoneButton()
{
    NextPlayerTurn();
    DeActivateLastInput();
    ShowInputField();
}
```

Comment: please i am not deactivating the last input field but rather the previous input fields that has already been added

Comment: The example code in my answer is **not** deactivating anything. It disables input on the `InputField`. You want the last input to be visible but not able to be modified? Then try this before making further comments.

Comment: I tried your example code and I get the error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GameController.ShowInputField () (at Assets/Scripts/GameController.cs:73)
GameController.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/GameController.cs:55)` also I want the last input field to be modifiable but not the previous ones

Comment: When I say last input, I meant previous one. There was a typo in the example script I provided. I updated it. Please, try it again.

Comment: i resolved the error by making the `GameObject lastInput` public and i assigned the InputField prefab to it in the editor but the code seems not to be doing anything.

Comment: *"i resolved the error by making the GameObject lastInput public and i assigned the InputField prefab to it in the editor"* That's so wrong. What's the point of using something else and complaining that it does not work. Like I said, use the updated code in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. this works perfectly... but i want to trouble you by asking this question. How can I get the text of every instance of the prefab and assign it to one string. Say i have a string `string word` that every letter entered is assigned to.

Comment: Create a `List` then add that instance to it every time there is a new instance. When you need the text, use `for` loop to loop over them then get the strings from the `List`. You can ask a new question if you are still confused.

Comment: I have a new problem related to the above codes should I ask a new question or edit this question? @Programmer

Comment: This comment section is long enough plus this post is about a month old. Please create new question

Comment: i have done that here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750823/destroy-instance-of-all-prefab-clone-not-working