# Destroy instance of all prefab clone not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a restart function where i want to delete the instance of all prefabs belonging to a panel. This code adds a new input field to the parent

```
private void ShowInputField(){

    GameObject inputFieldGameObject = inputFieldObjectPool.GetObject();

    //reset pool since it may have been disabled by the DeActivatePreviousInputFields function
    InputField inputField = inputFieldGameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
    inputField.Select ();
    inputField.ActivateInputField ();
    inputField.interactable = true;
    inputField.readOnly = false;

    //make this the previous inputs
    previousInputs = inputFieldGameObject;

    //assign the prefab to its parent panel
    inputFieldGameObject.transform.SetParent (inputFieldParent);
    inputFieldGameObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases ();

    //make scroll bar always show the last added input field
    GameObject.Find ("ScrollView").GetComponent<ScrollRect> ().horizontalNormalizedPosition = 1;

}
```

The image below shows how it looks like before the restart
[image: before restart]

the code for the restart which destroys all instances of the prefab and adds one again is shown below.

```
void RestartGame(){
    //gets all elements of the parent 
    InputField [] childElements = letterPanel.GetComponentsInChildren<InputField> ();
    Debug.Log (childElements.Count());
    foreach (var item in childElements) {
        Destroy (item);
    }
    ShowInputField()
}
```

this is supposed to destroy all instances of the prefab but it does not it only makes them editable with the image below showing it

[image]

How do I solve this problem? Thank you in advance...

Comment: What does `Debug.Log (childElements.Count())` show? Maybe it is actually destroying them but `ShowInputField()` is creating the new ones you see. Can you verify this by commenting out `ShowInputField()`.

Comment: i have done that i get the same output as above. The `ShowInputField()` will show a new input field

Comment: What does Debug.Log (childElements.Count()) show?

Comment: I was checking to see if the childElements had been loaded into the array

Comment: I have solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it worked

```
void RestartGame(){
    //gets all elements of the parent 
    InputField [] childElements = letterPanel.GetComponentsInChildren<InputField> ();
    Debug.Log (childElements.Count());
    foreach (vInputField item in childElements) {
        if(item.name.Contains("InputField")){
            Destroy (item.gameObject);
        }
    }
    ShowInputField()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were trying to destroy the current item from the list you were enumerating through, but this is an input field which you can cannot destroy. Instead by referring to the gameobject it belongs to and destroying that, you remove the Input fields.